# Break highcharts legend items into two lines

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with 10 series, so i want to break the series legends into 4 in first row and 6 in another. Is there a way to do this? Playing with legend.itemWidth and legend.width does no good. Please let me know if this is a known challenge? Or is there a workaround for this. I have pasted a screenshot below on what i am trying to achieve.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could create a custom legend instead

Comment: Could you add in your highcharts code as well? At least what you have so far regarding the legend so it is easier to fiddle with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highcharts **wrap** method to create your own customization for legend layout:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Legend.prototype, 'render', function(proceed) {
  proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

  var legend = this,
    legendWidth = legend.legendWidth,
    items = legend.allItems,
    firstLineWidth = 0,
    secondLineWidth = 0,
    firstStartPoint,
    secondStartPoint;

  Highcharts.each(items, function(item, i) {
    if (i < 4) {
      firstLineWidth += item.itemWidth;
    } else {
      secondLineWidth += item.itemWidth;
    }
  });

  firstStartPoint = (legendWidth - firstLineWidth) / 2;
  secondStartPoint = (legendWidth - secondLineWidth) / 2;

  Highcharts.each(items, function(item, i) {
    if (i < 4) {
      item.legendGroup.attr({
        translateX: firstStartPoint
      });
      firstStartPoint += item.itemWidth;
    } else {
      item.legendGroup.attr({
        translateX: secondStartPoint,
        translateY: 18
      });
      secondStartPoint += item.itemWidth;
    }
  });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7he9btvg/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I tried your wrapper function, i get an empty array for legend.allItems. something i am missing?

Comment: Does the example on jsfiddle work correctly for you?

Answer (score 0):

As Sachi Tekina noted, the best way to accomplish this would be a custom legend. The way that Highcharts legends are built and assembled means you cannot break them into two lines as you've shown in your example, either in the code options or after the fact using CSS (mainly because they use `position: absolute`, which could end up being a monumental pain to fiddle with).

Here's an example of a custom legend I built using one of the Highcharts demos: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/g0tfe12j/

First, build your custom legend using checkboxes. Note the break tag to push some to a second line.

```
<div align="center">
  <form id="test" name="test" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxClass" name="myCheckbox" series="Tokyo" id="checkbox1" checked><label for="checkbox1">Tokyo</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxClass" name="myCheckbox" series="New York" id="checkbox2" checked><label for="checkbox1">New York</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxClass" name="myCheckbox" series="Berlin" id="checkbox3" checked><label for="checkbox1">Berlin</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxClass" name="myCheckbox" series="London" id="checkbox4" checked><label for="checkbox1">London</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Next, you can use a function to trigger whenever the checkboxes are clicked. This function will look at the custom attribute in each checkbox ("series") and turn on or off the related series in your chart:

```
// when a checkbox is clicked, trigger the function
$(".myCheckboxClass").on('click',function() {
        // get the value of "series", a custom attribute for the checkbox
        var seriesName = $(this).attr("series");
        // if that value matches a series, show or hide it in the chart
        for (i = 0; i < $("#container").highcharts().series.length; i++) {
            if ($("#container").highcharts().series[i].name == seriesName) {
                // if the checkbox is checked, show the dataset
                if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                    $("#container").highcharts().series[i].show();
                // if the checkbox is unchecked, hide the dataset
                } else {
                    $("#container").highcharts().series[i].hide();
                }
            }
        }
});
```

You can then use whatever styles you like to match the custom legend to your chart.

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mike. Question, how would you inject this html into the drawLegendSymbol wrapper or into a framework like Backbone?

Comment: @arjary I'm afraid I don't have the expertise to advise you on how to get the HTML into the wrapper or Backbone; I'm not familiar with either. When I've built custom legends, they're part of the HTML content I use, with the JS either folded into or added separately from proprietary scripts. Here's another example I've built: https://www.frbatlanta.org/research/inflationproject/stickyprice.aspx. In this case, the HTML part of the object lives in our content management system, and the JS is inline code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Well, this will not work for me as i have a framework like backbone that has a View and a template concept. Your answer would need me to place that html in a separate template, even if i did that establishing the relation between the chart and the html view would be challenging.
It would have been great if i could inject that html into the wrapper function or someway into highcharts.